# SignalR not working with domain folder

Tags: javascript, iis, signalr

I created an app which uses SignalR that has been working beautifully when running in Visual Studio's local IIS web server (eg. http://localhost:12345).  I then switched to a custom web server using IIS which uses a domain folder (eg. http://localhost/test).  Now SignalR doesn't work.  It's attempting to user the following URL as the negotiate path:

```
http://localhost/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol......
```

As you can see, it doesn't have the subdomain `test` after `http://localhost/`.

I did some searching and found people using `$.connection.hub.url` to resolve the issue, but I'm unable to get this to work:

```
function init() {
    connection = $.hubConnection();
    hub = connection.createHubProxy('myHub');
    $.connection.hub.url = baseUrl + 'signalr';
    connection.start();
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a subdomain.  A subdomain would be `subdomain.domain.com`.  In your case, you're talking about a folder, not a subdomain.

Comment: @Amy: Oops.  Corrected.

Comment: I wonder if you also need to provide the new path in the `MapSignalR` call...

Comment: @Pawel: Your suggestion was interesting and ultimately led me to finding the solution (thanks!).  It turns out nothing has to happen server-side; SignalR is already being hosted on `http://localhost/domainFolder/signalr`.  See my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up stumbling upon the solution in [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#signalrurl) article.

You just need to pass the domain folder into the `$.hubConnection()` method like this:

```
function init() {
    connection = $.hubConnection('domainFolder');
    hub = connection.createHubProxy('myHub');
    connection.start();
};
```